# How to create a download m3u file from a url in c#?

Tags: c#, url, playlist, m3u, asx

I have web api application for online Radio,based on the url I want to create `.m3u`,`.asx`, `.pls`, `.ram` files. How to generate these files  in C#?

Comment: Please be more specific when you ask questions. For reference, see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first please. What is your actual problem? What have to tried to solve it? What research has been done?